# Open-addressed C hashmap

Tags: c, hash-map

I implemented an open-addressed, double-hashed hashmap in C, now looking for some advice on improving it. Thank you.

hashmap.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct hm_hashmap_t *hm_hashmap_t;

hm_hashmap_t hm_init(void);
void hm_destroy(hm_hashmap_t hm);

void hm_set(hm_hashmap_t hm, const char *key, void *val);
void *hm_get(hm_hashmap_t hm, const char *key);
void hm_delete(hm_hashmap_t hm, const char *key);

typedef struct hm_iterator_t *hm_iterator_t;

hm_iterator_t hm_iteratorInit(hm_hashmap_t hm);
void hm_iteratorDestroy(hm_iterator_t iter);

bool hm_iteratorNext(hm_iterator_t iter);
char *hm_iteratorKey(hm_iterator_t iter);
void *hm_iteratorVal(hm_iterator_t iter);
```

hashmap.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include "hashmap.h"
#include "hashfuncs.h"

#define INITIAL_BASE_SIZE 100

#define PRIME1 151
#define PRIME2 163

#define HIGH_DENSITY 70

typedef struct
{
  char *key;
  void *value;
} hm_item;

struct hm_hashmap_t
{
  long size;
  long count;
  hm_item **items;
};

struct hm_iterator_t
{
  hm_hashmap_t hm;
  long cursor;
  bool finished;
  char *key;
  void *val;
};

static hm_item HM_DELETED_ITEM = {NULL, NULL};

enum itemType
{
  empty,
  deleted,
  normal
};

static long sizes[] = {1009, 2027, 8111, 16223, 32467, 64937, 129887, 259781, 519577, 1039169, 2078339, 4156709, 8313433, 16626941, 33253889};

static int currentSizeIndex = 0;

#define sizeLength sizeof(sizes) / sizeof(sizes[0])

typedef struct
{
  long index;
  enum itemType type;
} itemIndex;

/*
 * private methods
*/

static hm_item *hm_newItem(const char *k, void *v)
{
  hm_item *item = malloc(sizeof(hm_item));
  item->key = strdup(k);
  item->value = v;
  return item;
}

static hm_hashmap_t hm_initSized(const int newSize)
{
  hm_hashmap_t hm = malloc(sizeof(*hm));
  hm->size = newSize;
  hm->count = 0;
  hm->items = calloc((size_t)hm->size, sizeof(hm_item *));

  return hm;
}

static void hm_resize(hm_hashmap_t hm, const long newSize)
{
  if (newSize >= sizes[sizeLength - 1])
  {
    return;
  }

  hm_hashmap_t tmpHm = hm_initSized(newSize);
  if (tmpHm == NULL)
  {
    return; // if there wasn't enough memory, just return
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < hm->size; i++)
  {
    hm_item *item = hm->items[i];
    if (item != NULL && item != &HM_DELETED_ITEM)
    {
      hm_set(tmpHm, item->key, item->value);
    }
  }

  hm->count = tmpHm->count;

  const long tmpSize = hm->size;
  hm->size = tmpHm->size;
  tmpHm->size = tmpSize;

  hm_item **tmpItems = hm->items;
  hm->items = tmpHm->items;
  tmpHm->items = tmpItems;

  hm_destroy(tmpHm);
}

static itemIndex hm_findItemIndex(hm_hashmap_t hm, const char *key)
{
  long index = strHash(key, PRIME1, hm->size);

  hm_item *item = hm->items[index];

  int i = 1;
  while (item != NULL)
  {
    if (item == &HM_DELETED_ITEM)
    {
      return (itemIndex){index, deleted};
    }
    else if (strcmp(item->key, key) == 0)
    {
      return (itemIndex){index, normal};
    }

    index = strDoubleHash(key, hm->size, PRIME1, PRIME2, i);
    item = hm->items[index];
    i++;

    if (i > hm->size)
    {
      // out of memory
      exit(1);
    }
  }
  return (itemIndex){index, empty};
}

static void hm_deleteItem(hm_item *item)
{
  free(item->key);
  free(item);
}

static void hm_iteratorFindNext(hm_iterator_t it)
{
  long cur = it->cursor + 1;
  while (cur < it->hm->size)
  {
    if (it->hm->items[cur] != NULL && it->hm->items[cur] != &HM_DELETED_ITEM)
    {
      it->cursor = cur;
      it->key = it->hm->items[cur]->key;
      it->val = it->hm->items[cur]->value;
      return;
    }

    ++cur;
  }

  it->finished = true;
}

/*
 * public methods
*/

hm_hashmap_t hm_init()
{
  return hm_initSized(sizes[0]);
}

void hm_destroy(hm_hashmap_t hm)
{
  for (long i = 0; i < hm->size; i++)
  {
    hm_item *item = hm->items[i];
    if (item != NULL && item != &HM_DELETED_ITEM)
    {
      hm_deleteItem(item);
    }
  }
  free(hm->items);
  free(hm);
}

void hm_set(hm_hashmap_t hm, const char *key, void *value)
{
  itemIndex i = hm_findItemIndex(hm, key);

  if (i.type == normal)
  {
    free(hm->items[i.index]->value);
    hm->items[i.index]->value = value;

    return;
  }

  hm_item *item = hm_newItem(key, value);
  hm->items[i.index] = item;
  hm->count++;

  long long load = hm->count * 100 / hm->size;
  if (load > HIGH_DENSITY && currentSizeIndex < (int)(sizeLength - 1))
  {
    hm_resize(hm, sizes[++currentSizeIndex]);
  }
}

void *hm_get(hm_hashmap_t hm, const char *key)
{
  itemIndex i = hm_findItemIndex(hm, key);
  return i.type == empty || i.type == deleted ? NULL : hm->items[i.index]->value;
}

void hm_delete(hm_hashmap_t hm, const char *key)
{
  itemIndex i = hm_findItemIndex(hm, key);

  if (i.type == empty || i.type == deleted)
  {
    return;
  }

  hm_deleteItem(hm->items[i.index]);
  hm->items[i.index] = &HM_DELETED_ITEM;
  hm->count--;
}

hm_iterator_t hm_iteratorInit(hm_hashmap_t hm)
{
  hm_iterator_t it = malloc(sizeof(*it));
  it->hm = hm;
  it->cursor = -1;
  it->finished = false;

  return it;
}

void hm_iteratorDestroy(hm_iterator_t iter)
{
  free(iter);
}

bool hm_iteratorNext(hm_iterator_t iter)
{
  if (iter->finished)
    return false;

  hm_iteratorFindNext(iter);
  return !iter->finished;
}

char *hm_iteratorKey(hm_iterator_t iter)
{
  return iter->hm->items[iter->cursor]->key;
}

void *hm_iteratorVal(hm_iterator_t iter)
{
  return iter->hm->items[iter->cursor]->value;
}
```

hashfuncs.h:

```
#pragma once

long strHash(const char *s, const int p, const long m);

long strDoubleHash(const char *s, const long m, const int p1, const int p2, const int numAttempts);
```

hashfuncs.c:

````
long strHash(const char *s, const int p, const long m) {
    long long hashValue = 0;
    long long pPow = 1;
    while(*s != '\0') {
        hashValue = (hashValue + *s++ * pPow) % m;
        pPow = (pPow * p) % m;
    }
    return hashValue;
}

long strDoubleHash(const char *s, const long m, const int p1, const int p2, const int numAttempts) {
    const long hash1 = strHash(s, p1, m);
    if (numAttempts == 0) {
      return hash1;
    }
    else {
      const long hash2 = strHash(s, p2, m);
      return (hash1 + (numAttempts * (p2 - hash2 % p2))) % m;
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impressive...

### hashing

I would suggest that the strHash just take the string, the strDoubleHash not exist, and the hash map code handle making the first and second hash values.
This would facilitate putting other hashes of different types of keys in.

As a hint: assume strHash is expensive, and minimize it's calls.

### deleted

I suspect there is a flaw in hm_findItemIndex about deleted items.  If you:

1. place item X at location n
2. try placing item Y again at location n, so it gets location m instead
3. delete item X
4. try to get item Y

At this point, hm_findItemIndex will return (n,deleted) instead of (m,normal), and Y has disappeared.
hm_findItemIndex must skip deleted, except for a special case for hm_set().  For hm_set(), you can use one pass to find an existing Y, and a second to find a deleted entry you can fill, and the first pass could return that there was a deleted, or even search to the empty and then return the deleted.

### fractions

```
  long long load = hm->count * 100 / hm->size;
  if (load > HIGH_DENSITY && currentSizeIndex < (int)(sizeLength - 1))
```

well, load will be between 0 and 70.  No need for long long, or even long or int.
However, you might overflow before then.  Try:

```
  int load = (int)(((long long)hm->count) * 100 / hm->size);
```

On the other hand, you might be better with changing HIGH_DENSITY to 0.70 and writing:

```
  if ((hm->count > (hm_size * HIGH_DENSITY)) && 
       currentSizeIndex < (int)(sizeLength - 1))
```

### currentSizeIndex

currentSizeIndex is a global.  Get rid of it.  Add a function to pick a size from your list given a minimum needed size.  This only is needed when you make an initial hash or when you enlarge the hash.

Speaking of which, if the caller knows he is going to add 5000 items, he should be able to access hm_initSize() telling it 5000, which should then back out the HIGH_DENSITY and find the right size in the list.

### Size List

Curious choices.  Primes less than \$2^n\$, but not the largest such primes.  Why not?

Edit: two additional thoughts

### Memory Management##

Currently you duplicate and free the keys, and leave the caller responsible for the values.  If you wish to continue this, hm_set() and hm_delete() should return the removed values for deletion, if needed.

Alternatively, the could be configuration in the hm_init() saying how to delete the value entries.  (This would be a function to call, with stock functions for do nothing and call free().)  There could also reasonably be a need to clone the value entries.

### Other Key Types

Other key types would also be good.  hm_init would need to be passed: a clone function, a free function, a compare function, and a hash function.  For keys that are stable and lasting, the clone could could return its parameter and the free do nothing.

Having hm_init() variants that provide the default string version would be quite reasonable.